# Unexpected Token - Syntax error in my node.js code

Tags: node.js, syntax-error, unexpected-token

I'm getting:

> Unexpected token - Syntax error in the 19TH line (in * *) code.

Please help. I'm fairly new to node.js.

This is the error in full:

> The deployment of your Cloud Function failed:
>   Function failed on loading user code. Error message: Code in file index.js can't be loaded.
>   Is there a syntax error in your code?
>   Detailed stack trace: /srv/index.js:20
>   }exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
>    ^^^^^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');const requestNode = require('request');
const NUMBER_ARGUMENT = 'number';process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statementsfunction saveToDb(numberToSave) {
    const options = {
        url: 'https://dog-pictures-2d717.firebaseio.com/picture.json',
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body : JSON.stringify({
            "number" : numberToSave
        })
    };
    requestNode(options, function(error, requestInternal, body){
        console.log(body);
*> });*

}exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

  function welcome(agent) {
    agent.add(`Welcome to my agent!`);
  }

  function fallback(agent) {
    agent.add(`I didn't understand`);
    agent.add(`I'm sorry, can you try again?`);
  }

  function showPicture() {
      let number = request.body.queryResult.parameters[NUMBER_ARGUMENT];
      saveToDb(number);
    }// Run the proper function handler based on the matched Dialogflow intent name
  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
  intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);
  // Here you pass as first argument the name of the Intent
  intentMap.set('Show picture', showPicture);
  // intentMap.set('your intent name here', yourFunctionHandler);
  // intentMap.set('your intent name here', googleAssistantHandler);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove this symbols: *>, * and remove brace near **exports** keyword.

You should get this:

```
requestNode(options, function(error, requestInternal, body){
    console.log(body);
});
```

and

```
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment
```

I advice you to install package **ESLint**. It will help you find and fix problems in your code.